# UITableView Content Size Issue not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working with `Swift 4.0` where I want `UITableview` with both vertical and horizontal scroll.

I have set `contentSize` of my `UITableview`. If I change the frame of `UITableview` programmatically then `contentSize` of `UITableview` is not working.

If the frame is same as it is set using autolayout then the `contentSize` of `UITableview` is working fine.

Below is the code I have tried :

```
let height : CGFloat = CGFloat((self.transactionArr.count*60)+70)
let width = self.view.frame.size.width*2
self.tblWidth.constant = self.view.frame.size.width
self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```

Comment: Tableview can only scroll vertically !! . use UICollectionview instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your tableview in a ScrollView. Make sure your ScrollView size is the same with tableview. 
set your ScrollView width bigger than your container view and you can scroll your tableview horizontally.

Comment: Never put a tableView inside a scrollview, it's not good design and will cause you a lot of bugs and frustration related to user gesture recognition and detecting scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hack `UITableView` - it is designed to scroll only vertically. Check out `UICollectionView` instead, it is designed for both vertical and horizontal scrolling (although you can make it scroll just one way if that's your need) - [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview), or a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started).